# SQL Server Delete substring until comma or right bracket

Tags: sql-server

I have many strings, where I should delete substring
There is comma one line, but in another - no

```
'CREATE INDEX IDX_REESTR_SLCTNS_DATA_KO_SRC ON T_REESTR_SELECTIONS_DATA(KO_SRC_ID ASC)' 
'CREATE INDEX IDX_ACCOUNTINGS_DATADT ON ACCOUNTINGS (KO_SRC_ID ASC, DT_ACCOUNT ASC, DATA ASC)'
```

I have to delete `KO_SRC_ID ASC` string.
I tried

```
select @leftStr = left(@str, patindex('%(%', @str))
select @rightStr = ltrim(right (@str, len(@str) - patindex('%[,|)]%', @str)))
select @leftStr + @rightStr;
```

but I have problem with symbol index for serach

Comment: It looks like you're trying to work with a situation where the KO_SRC_ID column has been removed from your schema, and you need to fix your index scripts. Is that right? If so, just removing `KO_SRC_ID` won't quite help, since that would leave an invalid `create index` statement as the first line: `create index ... on T_REESTR_SELECTIONS_DATA()` If this is what you are trying to do, perhaps we can give you a way to do it.

Comment: no. It scripts for create new indexes, I try update sql for that

Comment: So what should happen to the `create index` statement on line 1 after executing your code? The one for `IDX_REESTR_SLCTNS_DATA_KO_SRC`

Comment: @allmhuran I going to add new string between braces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about replacing the value with the empty string:
`set @str = replace(@str, 'KO_SRC_ID ASC', '')`

And here's how to remove it once with and without `,`

```
set @str = replace(replace(@str, 'KO_SRC_ID ASC,', ''), 'KO_SRC_ID ASC', '')
```

Comment: but I have to delete comma after string too

Comment: like this? set @str = replace(@str, 'KO_SRC_ID ASC,', '')

Comment: hmm. I Can search comma after (

Comment: There aren't all strings have comma

Comment: like this? set @str = replace(replace(@str, 'KO_SRC_ID ASC,', ''), 'KO_SRC_ID ASC', '') now you're first removing with comma and then the remaining without.